# Excel - more criteria at the same time

Tags: button, excel, autofilter, vba

I've got a spreadsheet in my Excel 2010 workbork with a lot of data. This page can be sorted by the build in autofilter.
On another sheet I have made a button which does some of the sorting.
For example:

```
Sub forsteKvartalAftaleIndgaet()

'
    Sheets("AMRM01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<01-04", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets("Ark2").Select
End Sub

Sub andenKvartalAftaleIndgaet()
'

    Sheets("AMRM01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">01-04", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<01-07"
    Sheets("Ark2").Select
End Sub
```

When I do this the sheet shows the first and second quarter of the year. I've got two buttons which show the third quarter and fourth quarter of the year which looks like this:

```
Sub TredjeKvartalAftaleIndgaet()
'

    Sheets("AMRM01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">01-07", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<01-10"
    Sheets("Ark2").Select
End Sub


Sub FjerdeKvartalAftaleIndgaet()
'

    Sheets("AMRM01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">01-10", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<31-12"
    Sheets("Ark2").Select
End Sub
```

My problem: When I press the button (Second quarter) it filters and shows the second quarter. But when I press the "Third Quarter" button it removes the Second Quarter filter and shows the Third Quarter.

Is it possible to write some kind of VBA code which makes it possible to have both buttons pressed at the same time, like it's possible to do with the build in autofilter buttons?

If you're not quite sure what I mean, please ask for a better explanation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? So it stands true for both ways? i.e.if

**1)** You select 2nd quarter first then it will show 2nd quarter and then when you press 3rd quarter, it will show you 2nd and 3rd quarter.

**2)** You select 3rd quarter first then it will show 3rd quarter and then when you press 2nd quarter, it will show you 2nd and 3rd quarter.

**Note**: I have not tested the code so let me know if you get any errors :)

```
Dim strCrt1 As String, strCrt2 As String, strCrt3 As String, strCrt4 As String

Sub andenKvartalAftaleIndgaet()
    strCrt1 = ">01-04"
    strCrt2 = "<01-07"

    With Sheets("AMRM01")
        If strCrt4 <> "" Then
            .Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=strCrt1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:=strCrt4
        Else
            .Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=strCrt1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:=strCrt2
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub TredjeKvartalAftaleIndgaet()
    strCrt3 = ">01-04"
    strCrt4 = "<01-07"

    With Sheets("AMRM01")
        If strCrt1 <> "" Then
            .Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=strCrt1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:=strCrt4
        Else
            .Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
            Criteria1:=strCrt3, Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:=strCrt4
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It do looks like we on the right track :) I'll try to test on my sheet, and see if it's working. As I read the code it looks like what I need.

I will make a simple example, as it is a lot easier for my to test. Thanks alot for your sugestions, I will report back later :)

Comment: It looks like some it is working, but I'm very confused :( I want to make 4 buttons, which divide the year into 4 quarters. From 01-01 to 01-04. From 01-04 to 01-07. From 01-07 to 01-10, and lastly from 01-10 to 31-12. I've tried but I can't figure out if sentence here.
I updated my code with all of it

Comment: Your solution worked, but it will be pretty complicated. I will se if I can work out a way to make it easier. Since i got 4 different buttons it will be a very long If.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand but it sounds like you simply want to show both quarter 2 and 3? I think you'd need its own macro for that.

```
Sub secondAndThirdQuarter()

    Sheets("AMRM01").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$P$76").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">01-04", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<01-10"
    Sheets("Ark2").Select

End Sub
```

Wouldn't that give the same result that you're looking for? I don't know if it's possible to filter on a filter with VBA.

Comment: Yes that's excactly what I want, but on 2 different buttons. I want that instead of endless combination of showing different quarters on different years :)